# Does solc generate the same byte code everytime?

Tags: solc

I came from this question: [How does Etherscan know the uncompiled contents of contracts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12721/how-does-etherscan-know-the-uncompiled-contents-of-contracts)

I'm wondering if the same solc compiler version would generate the same bytecode for the same contract every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's always generate same bytecode for same contract.